# Change all id's in HTMLDivElement using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery to dynamically append a Django formset.

I am using a link to add another form identical to the one above it. I do this with the following code:

```
var row = $("."+class_name).first().clone(true);
row.find('input').val('');
$(row).removeAttr('id').hide().insertAfter("."+class_name).last().slideDown(300);
```

Every label in row[0] (which is a HTMLDivElement) is id_cur-0-... And everytime I use this jQuery function to add a div, I need every id to increment the number after cur. So the first time I click it every item would have id_cur-1... And the next time they would have id_cur-2... And so on.

If I could treat the HTMLDivElement like a string I could use regex to basically find every occurrence of "cur-\d". How would I do this? Or is there a better way (because this kind of seems like a hack).

Here's what my HTML looks like:

```
<div class="item1">
  <label style="display:inline-block;" for="id_cur-0-cur_child_name">
    Name:
  </label>
  <input style="display:inline-block;width:10%" class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_cur-0-cur_child_name" name="cur-0-cur_child_name" type="text" />

  <label style="display:inline-block;" for="id_cur-0-cur_child_sex">
    Sex:
  </label>
  <input style="display:inline-block;width:10%" class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_cur-0-cur_child_sex" name="cur-0-cur_child_sex" type="text" placeholder="[M / F]" />

  <label style="display:inline-block;" for="id_cur-0-cur_child_dob">
    DOB:
  </label>
  <input style="display:inline-block;width:10%" class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_cur-0-cur_child_dob" name="cur-0-cur_child_dob" type="text" placeholder="e.g. 12/25/2014" />
</div>
```

Comment: providing your simple html will help more to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this do?

```
var last_id = $("."+class_name).last().attr("id").split("-")[1];
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5pedtq9/2/)

**UPDATE**

Hi there, the ev.preventDefault only serves the purpose of preventing the default behaviour of the anchor. It stops the default action of an element from happening.

I saw your html and here you have a new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5pedtq9/3/)

Javascript code (commented):

```
$("#clone").click(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    var row = $(".item1").last().clone(true);// Last item1
    var last_id = $(row).find("input:first").attr("id");// Grab first input id (it contains the important part: the number)
    row.find('input').val('');

    $.each(row.find('input'), function (index, item) {// Change id of all inputs inside the cloned element.
        var id = (+(last_id.split("-")[1])+1), // Grab the number and increase it.
            new_id = $(item).attr("id").replace("id_cur-" + last_id.split("-")[1], "id_cur-" + id);// Replace ids with the new number.
        $(item).attr("id",new_id);// Asign the new id to the inputs. You'll have to do more or less the same to the labels if you like.
    });
    $(row).removeAttr('id').hide().insertAfter(".item1:last").slideDown(300);// Insert after the last item1 element. Otherwise it'll insert after all elements with class .item1

});
```

Hope it helps.

Kind regards.

Comment: I'm messing around with the fiddle page you posted to understand this. What does the ev.preventDefault() do?

Comment: regardless I would this repeated for every instance. I don't know how to use the each function or map function for this specifically. But would that be a solution?

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. Although I think I will have to update the ```for``` and ```name``` in the HTML as well

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you can use id_cur as the class name, and the specific id with the id attribute as such:

```
var last_row = $("."+class_name+":last");
var new_row = last_row.clone(true);

new_row.attr('id', new_row.attr('id')+1);
new_row.find('input').val('');
new_row.removeAttr('id').hide().insertAfter(last_row)
new_row.slideDown(300);
```

You simply have to increment the id attribute with the last one + 1.

Just for clarification: You were using first() to select the first matched element and clone it in `var row = $("."+class_name).first().clone(true);`, but in this case, if we want to increment the id accordingly, we must clone the latest element added.

Hope this helps !

Cheers,

Comment: The id would be something like id_cur-0-cur-child-name. So I'm exactly sure what you mean by incrementing it

Answer (score 0):

*I could use regex to basically find every occurrence of "cur-\d".*

Use the JQuery regex selector to find all id or whatever attr.

1. Select all the label tag element in which the for attribute start with `id-cur-`

   ```
   $("label[@for^=id-cur-]")
   ```
2. Select all input tag element with id beginning with `id-cur-`

   ```
   $("input[@id^=id-cur-]")
   ```

Hope this may help to select the dom element with regex.

Comment: could you perhaps provide a little more information as to what to do with these two lines beyond this? This looks pretty intriguing if it does what I think it does...